# EOF while parsing a file containing images in python

Tags: python, image, eof, opencv

I don't understand why am I getting EOF error here. Can someone help, please?[here I am trying to iterate over a folder 'Flowers' containing 3 images which I want to display but I get EOF error no matter what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTiL.png)

[this is the error occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kurj8.png)

Also, the 2 lines of code which is not commented works when I display only 1 image. I want to display all the images, how can I do that?

Comment: sorry if the question is asked in a bad way

Comment: Why do you use screenshots rather than supplying the code in the post?  Maybe I don't understand what I'm seeing, but it seems that the error is simply due to your Python code having an 'for' statement with no body block.  It seems to be saying that it's reached the end of the file without finding the block.

Comment: Yes, this is a syntax error in the python source code, not an error parsing an image file.

Comment: Alright, I'll post the code

Comment: '''for img1 in images:
    img = cv2.imread(img1, 1)
    re = cv2.resize(img, (400, 400))
    cv2.imshow("Checking",re)
    cv2.imwrite("resized_"+img1,re)'''

Answer (score 0):

**WHY**: The EOF error is caused by a missing `for-loop` block. The syntax for a `for-loop` is:

```
for item in collection:
  # do something here..
  # do more stuff here..
```

or if the `for-loop` is empty, you need to specify `pass`.

```
for item in collection:
 #do nothing
 pass
```

In your code, there is nothing to execute, therefore, it requires a `pass` keyword.

---

**OBJECTIVE**: Having said the above, I think this is what you want to do:

```
image_path = "C:\\Users\PC\\Desktop\\Flowers\\{}"

images = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg"]
for image_name in images:
  image = Image.open(image_path.format(image_name))
  image.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I try to run the for loop, it gives me the EOF error.

Comment: Please be more specific with your comment, or recreate it.